# How to resolve this error in Odoo - 8?

Tags: odoo

I restored a database in Odoo and when I perform or click any operations, i am getting this error

**AttributeError: Field `res_manager` does not exist**

**Error context:
View `res.users.form`
[view_id: 153, xml_id: base.view_users_form, model: res.users, parent_id: n/a]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field doesn't exist in the core product so perhaps your database has a custom module that isn't in the add-ons path you are running now?  Odoo shows the addon's path in the first couple of lines of logging when it starts.

Comment: yes the problem was such kind, got it corrected yesterday itself. thank you

Comment: Then just make it a habbit to mark the correct answer as answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please reinstall your module by command line like this :

-Go to your server path in command prompt(Terminal)

-Restart your server with following command for 7.0

python open-server --addons-path=your_addons_path -d database_name -u app_name

Hope this work for you.

Comment: It works for my error. **Error context [view_id: 418, xml_id: account.invoice_form, model: account.invoice, parent_id: n/a]**